# Cant Connect to XML WebPage, Using SAX Parsing

Tags: android

In my **Android Project** when i try to connect to the follwing webpage,
**http://familytree-photoalbum.com/android.php?a=login&email=saqib.amin1@gmail.com&password=JLjZAT13**
 and to get the data parse, .. my Application get crashed, can not figure out, what em i leaving.

**Here is the Snipet of Parsing file.**

```
case R.id.bSignIn:
        String e = email.getText().toString(); // Getting Email from LoginPage
        String p = password.getText().toString(); // Getting Password from LoginPage
        StringBuilder URL = new StringBuilder(baseURL);
        URL.append(e + "&password=" + p);
        String fullUrl = URL.toString();

        new loadURL().execute(fullUrl);

        break;
```

**My AsyncTask that i am using.**

```
protected class loadURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Intent> {

    protected Intent doInBackground(String... fullUrl) {
        return xmlParsing(fullUrl[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Intent intent) {

        startActivity(intent);
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginPage.this, InvalidUser.class));
    }

}
```

**here is xmlParsing method, that is called from my AsyncTask**

```
protected Intent xmlParsing(String url) {
    Intent activity = new Intent();
    try {

        URL loginPage = new URL(url);

        // Getting XML Reader
        /**
         * The parse() method of SAXParser class reads the contents. The
         * SAXParserFactory is a factory API that enables applications to
         * configure and obtain a SAX parser to parse XML documents. The
         * startElement() method retrieves all starting elements and prints
         * them on the console. Whenever an error occurs it throws the
         * SAXException.
         */

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        HandlingLoginPage doingWork = new HandlingLoginPage();
        xr.setContentHandler(doingWork);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(loginPage.openStream()));

        Log.i("info", doingWork.code());

        if ((doingWork.userInformation()) == true) {

            activity = new Intent(LoginPage.this, HomeScreen.class);

        } else
            activity = new Intent(LoginPage.this, InvalidUser.class);

    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        title.setText("Error");
    }

    return activity;

}
```

Here is the DefaultHandler class named **HandlingLoginPage.class**

```
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.content.Intent;

public class HandlingLoginPage extends DefaultHandler {
    String defineCode = null;
    boolean user = false;

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if (localName.equals("code")) {

        defineCode = attributes.getValue("data");
        if (defineCode.equals("IP")) {
            user = false;
        } else if (defineCode.equals("LS"))
            user = true;
    }

}

protected boolean userInformation (){
    return user;
}

}
```

Comment: are you doing all this on the ui thread?

Comment: Sory for late Reply, i had some Internet Problem @RoyJamesSchumacher , Yes, i am a beginner, ... and my partner, who is expert in PHP , is helping me, .. the problem i am getting is, i can not connect to the Web Site.

Comment: More over, i learned this technique from the videos, provided by the New Boston.
[link](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=6&number=156)

Answer (score 0):

on android you can not do any network action on the main ui thread you need to either run it in a seperate thread or use the [Async](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class to do it. Also make sure you have declared in your android manifest that you need access to the internet with the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: i tried to do it with the AsyncTask, and still giving me the same error, i want to upload the code, so if there is some way you can check it ... i dont understand why it crashes down. :(

Comment: i have updated, this thread, with new code, .. @RoyJamesSchumacher

Comment: and also whats the error your actually getting saying?? @user2509009